# Understanding the behaviour of Reverse linked-list

Tags: c, function, linked-list, reverse, pseudocode

I was trying to understand what the below function is doing. Any explanation would truly be appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried working through it with pencil and paper? It's not very difficult. I suggest you start with a null pointer, then a list with only one element, then a list of two, then a list of three, and so on.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Looks to me like the pseudocode traverses the list to the end using recursive calls. Once it reaches the end, it then unrolls the recursion returning the last link at the end of the list. So the variable `listB` points to the end of the list. However the function also modifies the list link data, not the data in the list but rather the list management data, as the recursion unrolls. Looks to me like it reversing the order of the list.

Comment: *"I was trying to understand..."*: please add what you tried, how you approached it, what you researched, which points are clear, and where you got stuck.